# Multiplying stochastic volatility models: Application of multi-dimensional Ito formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have the following two stochastic volatility models:

$ d S_1 = r_1 S_1 dt + \sqrt{v_1} S_1 d W_1 \\
d v_1 = a_1 dt + b_1 d Z_1 \\
$

together with $d W_1 d Z_1 = \rho_1 dt$ and

$ d S_2 = r_2 S_2 dt + \sqrt{v_2} S_2 d W_2 \\
d v_2 = a_2 dt + b_2 d Z_2 \\
$,

with $d W_2 d Z_2 = \rho_2 dt$

If I define $X_1 := \left(\begin{matrix} S_1 \\ v_1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $X_2 := \left(\begin{matrix} S_2 \\ v_2 \end{matrix} \right)$, can I consider the quantity $d (X_1 X_2)$ ?

I would write

$ d (X_1 X_2) = X_1 d X_2 + X_2 d X_1 + d <X_1,X_2>$,

but I am not really sure how to do all the computations explicitly.

Any help or hint is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the meaning of $X_1X_2$? it is the product of two vectors

Comment: Yes, exactly! Is it possible to multiply them?

Comment: You must define the multiplication of two vectors , it can be anything ( dot product , tensor product ...)  Why do you want to multiply them ?

Comment: This is indeed my problem...how could I define it? As far as I know, matrix multiplication should be used in multi-dimensinal Ito formula, but by doing so, I don't know how to deal with $X_1 d X_2$. What do you suggest? I guess dot product could be a good choice, but the formula involves also matrix multiplcation....

Comment: Where did you get that question from ? You should not mention $X_1 d X_2$ as long as you have not define on which term you want to apply Ito's lemma. My guess is that your question is on the dot product.

Comment: Well, I would like to apply Ito's lemma to find the dynamics of the product of the two stochastic processes. My problem is: I am not really sure about how to define the product of $X_1$ and $X_2$. What I don't like about the dot product is that I would end up with a scalar process, while my aim is to get a third stochastic volatility model...what about a component-wise multiplication?